# LocalStorage to redirect Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, local-storage

I'm creating a Windows Phone 7.5 application which, in theory, should start a page which should be shown only once. Let's call it `SplashPage.xaml`. SplashPage.xaml contains two buttons with different parameter values:
  This is the English button, and there's another button as well:

```
    private void chooseEnglish_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        languageChooser.Add("languageChooser", "English");
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=English", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

However, at the moment I'm also saving a `LocalSettings` value, "languageChooser" with the value "English" upon click, which is stored in the `ApplicationSettings` called languageChooser. Now, what I'd like it to do is basically:
If (languageChooser contains either "Norwegian" or "English" as values)
-> Redirect the user automatically upon start (entering SplashPage.xaml) to the MainPage.xaml
else
-> the user picks a language, and the value is stored based on the button he/she clicks on.

I hope that's enough information. As of now, the beginning of the SplashPage.xaml.cs looks
like this:

```
    public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if ((string)languageChooser["languageChooser"] == "Norwegian" || (string)languageChooser["languageChooser"] == "English")
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=Norwegian", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void chooseEnglish_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    languageChooser.Add("languageChooser", "English");
    languageChooser.Save();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=English", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Your clickevent was missing Save. Which would save the value to ApplicationSettings.

```
public SplashPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string language;
    languageChooser.TryGetValue("languageChooser", out language);
    if (language != null)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=" + language, UriKind.Relative));
    }

}
```

When loading value on startup of your application. At the first run there's no value with they key so you need to use TryGetValue method.

Answer (score 1):

in `App.xaml.cs` you have a void for `Application Launching` and `Application Activated` i assume that you have a void for loadind settings, just add another one for default language

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {         
        LoadSettings();
        DefaultLanguage();
    }
```

and do something like this

```
 void DefaultLanguage() 
    {
            if (languageChooser==null)
            {
                ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/SplashPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            }
            else if (languageChooser =="Norwegian")
            {
                ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=Norwegian", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if (languageChooser =="English")
            {
                ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Language=English", UriKind.Relative));
            }

        }
    }
```

and finaly in your `WMAppManifest` the fild `Navigation Page` must be empty.

I hope it will work for you.